# swift 3, iOS - UIImageView for background

Tags: swift3, ios10

I currently have several labels and buttons in a UIView. I am using Storyboards and I want to add an image to the background. I tried it this way:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named:"background.png")!)
```

But unfortunately, this does not look right in the larger screen sizes. I think that I need to add a UIImageView. When I added a UIImageView, I couldn't figure out how to set it to be in the background so my button and labels could still be seen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by going to the panel in Storyboards and moving the UIImageView above the container view that held the labels and buttons. The UIImageView remained inside of the View, but moved to the background (under the buttons and labels).

Answer (score 0):

In your storyboard:

1- Add a `UIImageView` (inside your main view and outside everything else) and set its image to the image you want.

2- setup its constraints properly to fill the screen (give it 0 from all sides).

3- From attribute inspector, set Content Mode property to Aspect Fit.

Comment: What are the differences between Aspect Fit, Aspect Fill, and Scale To Fill?

Answer (score 0):

```
let someImageView: UIImageView = {
    let theImageView = UIImageView()
    theImageView.image = UIImage(named: "yourImage.png")
    return theImageView
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.addSubview(someImageView) //This add it the view controller without constraints
}

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

    someImageView.frame = view.bounds
}
```